# Selenium Python - Verify either of the title with EC.title_contains() method

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify either of the page title "Apple" or "Mango" using `EC.title_contains()` method.

I have tried below but does't work for both the pages.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("Apple") or EC.title_contains("Mango"))

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("Apple" or "Mango"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Check if below lines can help you to know the page by page title, change the driver path..

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe", options=opt)
driver.get("http://rera.rajasthan.gov.in/ProjectSearch")

WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(lambda driver: 'Mango' in driver.title or 'RER' in driver.title)

search_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn_SearchProjectSubmit"]')
# invoke the click() action
search_btn.click()
```

For Element below lines need to import By

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'xpath') or driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'xpath2nd'))
```

Comment: Hi, it failed after swapping `WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.title_contains('RER') or EC.title_contains('Mango'))` with `WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.title_contains('Mango') or EC.title_contains('RER'))`.  error is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tkumar3/Desktop/Day1/untitled1/slenium.py", line 135, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.title_contains('Mango') or EC.title_contains('RER'))
  File "C:\Users\tkumar3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
   raise TimeoutException`

Comment: did you run the code as it is before changing , its working fine... can you share link to pages which you are using

Comment: If I run your code without any change then it works fine but if I use `WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.title_contains('Mango') or EC.title_contains('RER'))` then it fails. Similarly I have two websites to test which uses same library. Sorry websites are not publicly accessible.

Comment: @yash -  Run the code now , I have replaced wait line.